# SQL Consulta autodelete

Tags: mysql, sql

Como eu poderia fazer uma consulta autodeletavel no SQL, Ou seja eu gostaria de consultar tal valor e deletar em seguida em apenas uma consulta só. EX:

```
select * from usuarios where nome=lucas
```

ou seja receber o resultado de buscar e apagar.

Eu sei que daria para depois apagar usando:

```
DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE nome = lucas
```

Mas não é isso que eu quero, Eu queria saber se em apenas uma consulta é possível retornar o valor e logo apagar em seguida.

Comment: Pra qual finalidade você quer obter tudo numa consulta só?? Não faz muito sentido isso.

Comment: Diego, acho que ele quer exibir todos que foram excluídos. Então acho que se for isso, ele quer fazer algo bem prático numa única query. Pode ser interessante se existir uma função nativa que permita tal execução. Apesar de não fazer muito sentido.

Comment: @DanielOmine se for isso, só me vem a mente store procedure ou transaction.

Comment: Me faz uma falta danada esse recurso. Infelizmente vai ter que fazer duas operações mesmo. Ao menos eu desconheço maneira de deletar obtendo retorno. E parece que o pessoal não entendeu a pergunta.

Comment: Bacco5, Você entendeu perfeitamente a minha pergunta kkk Obrigado, E Obrigado também a todos aqueles que por mais que não entenderam muito bem, Tiveram a paciência de vir aqui dar uma atenção, Valeu pessoal, Bom tive que optar por fazer da forma tradicional que é 2 consultas.

Comment: seria isso que você quer? `DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE nome like '%lucas%'`;

Comment: Se você deleta um registro não tem como trazê-lo nesta mesma query. Eu não entendi bem sua lógica. Mas o ideal é que você faça a consulta primeiro, achou o dado? OK, pode deletá-lo agora.

Answer (score 0):

É possível com a utilização de Stored Procedures:

```
/*Criar stored procedure*/
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE auto_remove(IN nome VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
  /*Criar uma tabela temporaraia para guardar o valor que você achou*/
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temporaryUser;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temporaryUser AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM pessoas
    WHERE pessoas.nome LIKE nome
  );

  /*Deletar o valor da tabela original*/
  DELETE FROM pessoas WHERE pessoas.nome LIKE nome;

  /*retornar o valor*/
  SELECT  * from temporaryUser;
END //
DELIMITER;
```

É uma solução rápida, e provavelmente não é a mais elegante, mas funcionou. O problema dessa solução é que apesar de reduzir o número de acessos ao banco, você tem que saber o quê são *stored procedures* para poder entender ela, mesmo não sendo difícil, requer o aprendizado para poder entender e dar manutenção a essa solução.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o comando RETURNING

`DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE nome = lucas RETURNING *;`

Você pode usar também o nome dos campos. Exemplo:

`DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE nome = lucas RETURNING id;`

Answer (score -2):

É preciso dois acessos a banco, um para procurar e outro para deletar. O que você pode fazer é um DELETE e SELECT na mesma query. Seria mais ou menos assim:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE colunaA=(SELECT colunaA FROM table_name WHERE colunaA = 'nome');
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo pela ajuda, Mas eu resolvi optar por fazer da forma tradicional que é 2 consultas. Obs: Por favor pessoal vamos ter um pouco mais de sensibilidade, As pessoas vem aqui com a intensão de ajudar e sempre tem uns para negativar as respostas ¬¬.